# Excel Dynamic Chart Data Selection with Sliding Window

Tags: excel

I'm new to Excel and macros/VBA and I've been trying to arrange create a graph with the aid of a table. This first part is fairly simple and easy and has been described several times all over the internet. I followed Mr. Peltier's tutorial and it works just fine when it comes to adding new data.

How does one create a graph from a table with a fixed number of rows and only using the data from the last 3 columns of the table? Is it possible to automate this process everytime a new column is added with a macro/VBA?

Basically I want to change the source data of my graph to the last 3 Columns.

I know this concept is known as a sliding window, but I haven't got much sucess searching for this type of use of sliding windows in Excel. Most the examples I've seen use the offset function and apply this concept of sliding windows to simple functions such as sums and what not.

Thank you.

Edit: this has been answered in

https://peltiertech.com/dynamic-chart-source-data/#comment-1465235

See the last comments

Comment: I'm not too sure on how it works but there might be something with the worksheet.change event and finding the last row.

Comment: @Brotato Mr. Peltier answered my question on his website. I posted the link in the post.